# Retrieving data from nested dict in python

Tags: json, python-2.7

i'm trying to parse data from a dict. following is the dict.

```
data = {'specs': u'{"software_addon": None, 
"checkout_os": 
    {12L: {"status": 3L, "units": 1L, "label": "Disk1", "orderproduct_id": 22L, "slider_id": 788L, "unitPrice": 0.3}, 
    15L: {"status": 3L, "units": 60L, "label": None, "orderproduct_id": 22L, "slider_id": 787L, "unitPrice": 0.3}}, 
"checkout_op": {"pk": 11L, "total_price": 90.3, "discount_price": 80.3, "monthly_fee": 80.3}, 
"virtualmachine_vm": {"pk": 15L, "diskGB": 101L, "memoy_size": 3221225472L, "num_cpu": 2L}, 
"checkout_o": {"pk": 74L, "grand_total": 180.3, "discount_price": 180.3}
}', 
'id': 411L, 'name': u'name-7xccf'}
```

when i would try to retrieve the data it gives the error.

```
print data['specs']['virtualmachine_virtualmachines']['pk']
```

error: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: print data['specs']['virtualmachine_vm']['pk']

Comment: data["specs"] is a string in your example, it expects a string to be indexed by an int like data['specs'][2].  you should probably remove some quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and got the same error as you (even with Eastwood's suggestion), but it worked after eliminating the `u'` and the corresponding closing quote.
Obviously one can't use this `u` operator/modifier for an entire dict.

So

```
data = {'specs': {"software_addon": None, "checkout_os": {12L: {"status": 3L, "units": 1L, "label": "Disk1", "orderproduct_id": 22L, "slider_id": 788L, "unitPrice": 0.3}, 15L: {"status": 3L, "units": 60L, "label": None, "orderproduct_id": 22L, "slider_id": 787L, "unitPrice": 0.3}}, "checkout_op": {"pk": 11L, "total_price": 90.3, "discount_price": 80.3, "monthly_fee": 80.3}, "virtualmachine_vm": {"pk": 15L, "diskGB": 101L, "memory_size": 3221225472L, "num_cpu": 2L}, "checkout_o": {"pk": 74L, "grand_total": 180.3, "discount_price": 180.3} }, 'id': 411L, 'name': u'name-7xccf'}
print data['specs']['virtualmachine_vm']['pk']
```

worked

Comment: still same error, when i print following it works fine. print data['name']

Comment: That's odd. Did you copy/paste the code I posted? I used Python 2.7.5 here and it printed the answer (15) without complaining

Comment: Technically you are right, this code works if i explicitly use this dict. My issue was with the construction of dict through. i had removed the extra quotes nut it didnt work. i was doing the operations on the complete dict. but it is resolved as i converted 'specs' to python dict and then added in to 'data' dict. it works now.